# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() in python (Password Generator)

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to create my own random password generator

```
import random

all = ['A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, !, ”, $, %, &, *, -, _, +, /, ~']

user_len = input('Enter the length of the password u want: ')

pass_len = len(user_len)
shuffle = random.shuffle(all)

shuffle_len = shuffle(len(pass_len))
```

And whatever I do, the "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" appear and that's error is for the shuffle_len variable

Comment: pass_len is already int, and you're checking its len again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `all` (which is not a good name for a variable as it shadows [the built-in function `all()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#all)) is a list containing one string that has a bunch of commas. (Trying to shuffle a list with one item is not going to do you much good.)

Chances are you want a list with each possible character as a single string; you can either spell that out (`'A', 'B', 'C', ...`) or have the `list()` function split a string up for you.

```
all = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!”$%&*-_+/~')
```

Next, `input()` returns a string, and so if you take `len()` off the value, you'd have to enter `six` to get a 3-letter password, `oooooooo` to get an 8-letter password, etc.

Instead, do

```
pass_len = int(input('Enter....'))
```

Next up, `random.shuffle()` doesn't return anything; it shuffles the input list in-place. `shuffle` will be None, so trying to call it would fail (if evaluating `len(pass_len))` didn't. Even if `random.shuffle` returned a list, you wouldn't be able to call it. Looks like you want a slice – the `pass_len` first items, instead.

You then have a list, but presumably you want to go back to a string, so you'll need to call `"".join()` on it to join up all of those single characters with nothing in-between.

All in all, you'll want:

```
import random

characters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!”$%&*-_+/~')
pass_len = int(input('Enter the length of the password u want:'))
random.shuffle(characters)
password = "".join(characters[:pass_len])
print(password)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Everything worked, but the result will be 

"Enter the length of the password u want:9
['2', 'R', 'F', 'O', '~', 'N', 'H', '-', '$']"

And I don't want to be like that, I want it to be as 1 word

Comment: I edited that in already – do `"".join(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

pass_len is a integer because return type of len function is integer. Then you can not write

```py
len(pass_len)
```

In your final line